# Android NDK app crashed when linking with OpenMp

Tags: android-ndk, openmp

In the Android NDK project, I linked with OpenMp in CMakeLists.txt by

```
find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    message("---- OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS: " ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS})
    message("---- OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS: " ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS})
    message("---- OpenMP_C_SPEC_DATE: " ${OpenMP_C_SPEC_DATE})
    message("---- OpenMP_CXX_SPEC_DATE: " ${OpenMP_CXX_SPEC_DATE})
    message("---- OpenMP_C_VERSION: " ${OpenMP_C_VERSION})
    message("---- OpenMP_CXX_VERSION: " ${OpenMP_CXX_VERSION})
    message("---- OpenMP_C_LIBRARIES: " ${OpenMP_C_LIBRARIES})
    message("---- OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES: " ${OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES})
endif (OPENMP_FOUND)
```

the program can compile and link correctly

```
C/C++: ---- OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS: -fopenmp=libomp
C/C++: ---- OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS: 
C/C++: ---- OpenMP_C_SPEC_DATE: 201811
C/C++: ---- OpenMP_CXX_SPEC_DATE: 201811
C/C++: ---- OpenMP_C_VERSION: 5.0
C/C++: ---- OpenMP_CXX_VERSION: 5.0
C/C++: ---- OpenMP_C_LIBRARIES: /home/me/Soft-android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.6/lib/linux/arm/libomp.so
C/C++: ---- OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES: /home/me/Soft-android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/14.0.6/lib/linux/arm/libomp.so
```

However, the program crashed immediately when launching, even when no OpenMp functions were called. Disabling the line `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")` makes the program launch again. However no OpenMp functions, e.g. `omp_get_wtime`, can be called. What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed by adding:

```
target_link_libraries(executable -fopenmp -static-openmp)
```